# Is there any difference between a plain old TwiML `Dial` verb and a single `Number` nested in a `Dial`?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Other than one being slightly more verbose than the other, functionally is there any difference between these two TwiML blocks, assuming there is no additional configuration? I was unable to find anything in the docs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>111-111-1111</Dial>
</Response>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>111-111-1111</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, both TwiML files are equivalent.